# Advantages on using a function generator against a multi-pulse generator by using a 555

Tags: 555, function-generator

I have designed a noise and interference reduction block. When I was going to test it by mounting the system in the lab, my professor told me that I could test it by creating a source of 50Hz by using a 555 in astable mode, instead of using the function generator as I was going to attempt.

After that, I was thinking what could be the advantages or disadvantages of testing that, with the function generator and with the multi-pulse generator. It took me a good deal of time to design the source with the 555, since it was unknown to me at that point.

So, I'd like to know the advantages and disadvantages of using both methods, to understand what was the point of using the multi-pulse generator with the 555.

Comment: Beyond the learning experience of working with a 555, I can't see any reason it'd be advantageous over using a function generator.

Comment: I agree with Nick.  There really is no advantage at all in testing something to designing and building an inferior circuit when a piece of lab equipment is available.

Comment: Well, why do professors tell people to do things? To learn about them...

Comment: Yeah, I thought that. It was way more straightforward to do it with the function generator. But I was just thinking if there was any advantage on using the other. I see it was just a matter of learning experience of working with a 555.

Answer (score 5):

If the function generator can produce the 50 Hz signal, then there is no advantage to the 555 timer electrically.

Function generator advantages:

Ready to use, just dial in what signal you want.

555 timer advantages:

It makes you learn about a 555 timer.

If you don't value your time (or your professor doesn't), it's a lot cheaper than a function generator.

It keeps 20 students from fighting over the single function generator.

Comment: This is a really good answer! Now I understand why the professor said that to us! Thank you!!